# Odd requests to non-existing pages that all include "6_S3_"

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-404

This has been going on for at least some months on our servers and I'm wondering what's responsible for it. A browser add-on? Trojan? From different users (including logged in members), at different times, we get requests for the current page where the last part is replaced by `6_S3_`

Some examples from the logs:

```
 REQUEST[/pt/collectors/collector/6_S3_] REFERER[http://colnect.com/pt/collectors/collector/ciccamozzo]

 REQUEST[/it/stamps/6_S3_] REFERER[http://colnect.com/it/stamps/countries]

REQUEST[/hu/account/6_S3_] REFERER[http://colnect.com/hu/account/my_lists]

REQUEST[/pl/coins/6_S3_] REFERER[http://colnect.com/pl/coins/countries]
```

Tried to search it on the Internet and have come up with nothing, hence this question. Thanks

Comment: First date detected in logs is 2015-01-07

Comment: We have same error. Users request URLs with 6_S3_ in the end of URL. This happened only our Chrome users. I suppose it's a browser extension. Also similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261822/fabicon-ico-or-unwanted-strings-like-6-s3-get-appended-after-the-callback-url

Comment: Sources say it's caused by the following script tag being injected in the source: `<script type="text/javascript" src="6_S3_"></script>`. If you have 10k rep, you can see a now-deleted question asking about it (it does not have any answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991243/javascript-tag-generated-automatically-in-my-code

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara don't have the rep to see it, can you attach some vital information? Is there a solution? Is it related to third party (such as Facebook) script?

Comment: The question was not well received and did not get any answers. [Here's a screenshot anyway](https://i.imgur.com/3IFLpqq.png). I would be curious to hear if anyone is experiencing this over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderO'Mara So likely a malware on the side of some users...

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the server you use this HTTP header solves the OP's problem and also provides additional security against XSS attacks:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src s.colnect.net *.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'
```

---

We also receive hundreds of request like this originating from iframe elements included in our partners' site. I haven't figured out exactly what causes it but I updated the web server (Apache) configuration to include a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) header in the response:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data:"
```

This prevents any injected content to be loaded or executed inside our frame, but it allows to use inline style tags and images with "data:" URIs which is enough in our case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We don't use apache and CSP support for script-src, according to the link you sent, doesn't seem well established.