# Requests to non-existing pages that all include "undefined”

Tags: javascript, http, undefined, server

Some odd requests appear on our logs since ~October 20, 2014. They've increased to about a few dozens a day so while not a big problem, it's still interesting to find out the reason.

Earlier ones:

```
REQUEST[/en/undefinedsf_main.jsp?clientVersion=null&dlsource=null&CTID=null&userId=userIdFail&statsReporter=false] REFERER[http://colnect.com/en/coins]
REQUEST[/fr/undefined/GoogleExtension/deals.html?url=http://colnect.com&subid=STERKLY&appName=HypeNet&pos=2&frameId=buaovbluurbavptkwyaybzjrqweypsbavwrviv] REFERER[http://colnect.com/fr]
REQUEST[/br/stamps/undefined49507173c45043eba6dfb9da540e52de&chnl=slmbBRex&evt=DailyPing&prd=vbates&seg=1&ext=1&rnd=65983fb77b62e25cc2a8ef15af18273d] REFERER[http://colnect.com/br/stamps/countries]
```

Some current ones:

```
REQ[/ru/collectors/collector/undefined] REF[http://colnect.com/ru/collectors/collector/jokitsos]
REQ[/th/collectors/collector/undefined] REF[http://colnect.com/th/collectors/collector/VRABEC]
REQUEST[/en/account/undefined] REFERER[http://colnect.com/en/account/request_password]
REQUEST[/pt/stamps/undefined] REFERER[http://colnect.com/pt/stamps/years]
```

Some requests are by logged in members and some not.

I'd guess some Javascript on their browser is trying to call a url by some uninitialized variable thus the "undefined".

Reasons may be similar to [Odd requests to non-existing pages that all include "6_S3_"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876860/odd-requests-to-non-existing-pages-that-all-include-6-s3) (perhaps malware) but I'm wondering if this might be a different reason.

I do doubt it's a bug on our client side Javascript as this would generate much more than a few dozens of such requests a day from about a million daily page views.

Any ideas? Is it worth pursuing?

Comment: Without relevant code, we can't help.

Comment: What do you mean by relevant code? This likely isn't about a code on our side but about requests coming from the client side. If our Javascript code is suspect then it can obviously be found on the REF[] or REFERER[] pages linked.

Comment: I don't think that user will manually enter that url (unless intentioned to break system). Maybe you generate some url with JS and some variable is undefined? Maybe you are referring to `.val()` for items with only `.text()` option.

Comment: As I couldn't find anywhere in my code that would do that, I suspect that perhaps 3rd party JS (GA/FB/...) might be responsible. That's why I started this question.

Comment: I think you're onto something there where you say that the url is dynamically generated - but certain values may be undefined, and thus you see the 'undefined' in the request. Not all clients must have this problem because sometimes this is browser and version dependent. E.g. JSON is undefined in IE8 ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8 ). So maybe you can check whether all these faulty request happen with some specific browser / client.

Comment: Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) for  user interaction debugging and see where this kind of requests are generated. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017609/undefined-randomly-appended-in-1-of-requested-urls-on-my-website-since-12-jun) might help.

Comment: @spike User-agents are from various browsers (IE/FireFox/Chrome) and various versions. .

Comment: @HadiRj I'm familiar with debugging tools but haven't been able to reproduce the error

Comment: @Collector you said that you doubt clientside because "this would generate much more than a few dozens of such requests a day from about a million daily page views." You also state that the user-agents are varied, so it isn't a browser edge case. Malware seems like a low possibility, especially if the user-agents include non-windows users. If your application serving millions of people has no possible edge cases that could generate a bad URL (or refresh the page and append an unknown slug), then it really sounds like a few random bad browser extensions.

Answer (score 6):

**This is a big concern, but it's not coming from you.**

These are **Javascript Injection** attacks (client machine malware) using **[self-signed root certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate)**.

Specifically, `sf_main.html`, and `deals.html` have been linked to **[Superfish](http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/02/19/superfish-need-to-know/)**, which has been shipping with Lenovo's recently. As Lenovo has been pushing its new lines of PC's, **[reports](https://superuser.com/questions/848853/what-is-best-deals-products-and-is-it-malware)** of the attacks have blown up recently.

These **[Man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)** attacks start by hijacking the client's requests and and then injecting **HTML** and **Javascript**.

The reason there are so many `undefined` symbols is because **Superfish**, true to it's name, is fishing for plugins, extensions, and libraries it can take advantage of using their expected names, tokens, and paths. This is brute force **XSS**.

### Oh, no, what can I do??

Little. Not much.

As the requests are being hijacked on the client machine and by `http request` hijacking, you won't know the difference. You could try to "fish" for certain kind of hostile "indicators" but now you are doing the work of Anti-Malware.

Lenovo [claims](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/superfish) that

> SuperFish has completely disabled server side interactions (since
>   January) on all Lenovo products so that the software product is no
>   longer active, effectively disabling SuperFish for all products in the
>   market

While I trust the sincerity of China-based Lenovo, which has serious market interests in the Western world, I wouldn't trust the word of China based malware company  **Superfish**.

**These attacks are less a problem for you than your customers**

Unless you work for a big bank or popular Social Networking site, it's highly unlikely that Malware like **Superfish**, has targeted you specifically. Your customer's bank and social network accounts are at risk, but not because of anything you did or can do to stop it.

As always, the cure for client side fishing attacks is good client side protection.

Comment: I haven't found anything about "undefined" appearing on server logs in any of the links you've included. How have you reached your conclusion and what evidence is there to establish it?

Comment: @Collector, I've asserted 1) that these are JavaScript Injection attacks, 2) that many of the references you noticed such as  `sf_main.html`, and `deals.html` are associated with SuperFish. That you can find in this link I included in my answer http://superuser.com/questions/848853/what-is-best-deals-products-and-is-it-malware

Comment: The `undefined` variables not mentioned in the posts, but otherwise your symptoms are identical. The links, their somewhat rare nature, and the opportunity for JavaScript Injection which came from having Central Authority on client computer's Certificates.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining but I still don't know if such issues would be caused by malware or a buggy addon/extension. I guess the nicest thing would be to log it in the user's session and then display a notice about it on the next page. Have any websites done that?

Comment: @Collector, that's an interesting idea. I can't rule out Extension Methods. All too many have become Trojan horse of Malware. Any data you can gleam would be helpful. In the case of SuperFish, this site scans the client machine for it's malicious behavior https://filippo.io/Badfish/

Comment: Malware and scanning could be the culprit, but those usually show up with multiple variations on the URLs within some scanning time range. Do the rest of the logs support the idea of URL scanning? I.E., did the hijacked browser submit to a lot of different bad URLs, or just this one? If the visitor's traffic looks like a single hit rather than a series of fishing attempts... then it's more likely to be a problem with URLs being generated in the clientside application.

Comment: @BenBrock, there's no way to be sure. Even extensively studying logs gives you the slightest glimpse into what happens on the client. Is it Malware? We can be sure of it. Javascript Injection can only happen from so many points. 99% of the time it's the client. Check out this Stack post, and pay close attention to the url file names, **sf_main.html** is a very distinct name http://superuser.com/questions/848853/what-is-best-deals-products-and-is-it-malware

Comment: @Collector, have you made any progress diagnosing this?

Comment: I currently believe it's either malware or problematic add-ons. Anyway, something on the client side I cannot do much about except warning the user. With this, I stopped further analyzing the situation.

Answer (score 4):

> Any ideas?

There seem to be two different options here:

1. There are mistakes in your code causing incorrect URLs to get generated
2. There are (search) bots trying to parse your Javascript and failing to do it correctly.
3. (A client side extension is stirring up trouble)

To differentiate between the two you would need to set up more specific logging. For example adding the user agents to any log lines containing the string `undefined` will answer this question. If it's your code causing the problem you would also wish to log the `referer` header, as it will expose on which page the faulty URL's are being generated.

Another way to identify the issue is if you have an analytics solution running on your site such as Google Analytics you can quite easily limit your report to only `url`'s containing `undefined`. If there are no such request you can conclude that it has to be a bot (as it wouldn't cause the client side analytics code to run), otherwise it provides all the information to identify where this problem is caused.

Lastly it might be a good idea to include a javascript error logging solution (in its simplest form a `window.onerror` handler with an ajax request to `\log.something`. If your code is generating `undefined`'s it's quite likely that some errors are being triggered as well.

---

> Is it worth pursuing?

If users are actually being served invalid pages, then yes, this is definitely something to be investigated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and ideas. Yes, the errors are present on GA but altogether are shown for <0.01% of pages which make me think it's a client side extension/malware that does these requests. Setting up a proper error logging for Javascript might be a good idea in general as well.

Comment: While the pages do sometimes appear on GA, most errors are only on the server side and never reach GA. I believe that supports the assumption.

Comment: If the URL results in an error page from the server - specifically, an error page that does not produce GA tracking codes - then it makes sense that you see only a fraction of these hitting GA. I bet those hitting GA are specific to catch-all URLs (something that will display a friendly "not found" error message)?